# SQL Query Across Multiple Joined Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've got three tables: Resource, Timesheet, TimePeriod. A Resource has many Timesheets and a Timesheet has one TimePeriod. This used for us to keep track of employee timesheets. I'm trying to figure out how to find out the status of each person's timesheet for this week. The problem is, if a person hasn't filled out a timesheet, then there will not be an entry in the timesheet table. So their status should be NULL.

This is what the database looks like:

```
Resource
id | Name 
---+------------
 1 | John Smith
 2 | Jason Bourne

Timesheet
id | Status    | Resource_Id |TimePeriod_Id
---+-----------+-------------------------------
 1 | Submitted | 1           | 1
 2 | Created   | 1           | 2
 3 | Submitted | 2           | 1


TimePeriod
id | Week 
---+----------------
 1 | 2013Week1
 2 | 2013Week2
 3 | 2013Week3
```

If the TimePeriod were stored in the same table then this wouldn't be a problem. But since its in a separate table I think there is a problem with the way I'm doing my joins. I can't figure out the query to make this work.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT res.id, res.name, ts.status
FROM Resource res
LEFT JOIN Timesheet ts ON ts.resource_id = res.id
LEFT JOIN TimePeriod tp ON ts.timeperiod_id = tp.id 
WHERE tp.week = '2013Week2'
```

This obviously eliminates Jason Bourne from the results because he has no timesheet

I also tried this:

```
SELECT res.id, res.name, ts.status
FROM Resource res
LEFT JOIN Timesheet ts ON ts.resource_id = res.id
LEFT JOIN TimePeriod tp ON ts.timeperiod_id = tp.id AND tp.week = '2013Week2'
```

Which returns extra rows and wrong data.

The desired result would be:

```
id  name           status    
1   John Smith     Created
2   Jason Bourne   NULL
```

I believe I could stumble my way through this with UNION, but I feel like there should be a way to do this other than that. If anyone has any advice I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you recheck your desired result?  I suppose you are expecting "1-John Smith-Created" and not "1-John Smith-Submitted".

Comment: You status for John Smith for 2013Week2 is Created not submitted

Comment: Good catch. I'll change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one:

```
SELECT r.id, r.Name, s.Status
FROM Resource r
INNER JOIN TimePeriod p ON p.week = '2013week2'
LEFT JOIN Timesheet s ON s.Resource_id = r.id AND s.TimePeriod_id = p.id
;
```

Alternatively you could replace the `INNER JOIN ... ON` with a `CROSS JOIN ... WHERE`:

```
SELECT r.id, r.Name, s.Status
FROM Resource r
CROSS JOIN TimePeriod p
LEFT JOIN Timesheet s ON s.Resource_id = r.id AND s.TimePeriod_id = p.id
WHERE p.week = '2013week2'
;
```

Although it must be said that MySQL doesn't distinguish between `CROSS JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`, treating those as synonyms of each other. Anyway, the above queries are standard SQL and would work in any SQL product.

A SQL Server demo at SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a0a1/2

Comment: Very nice. It's worth noting that if the OP wanted  `TimePeriod.Week` in the Select clause these would be better solutions than `LEFT JOIN (a inner join b on) ON`

Comment: @ConradFrix: Interestingly, I thought that if they wanted `Week` in the output then *your* suggestion would fit better, since mine would return the requested value for all the resources returned, even if some of them didn't have matching timesheets. I mean, I'd expect those to show nulls instead. Well, of course, there may be difference of opinions on which variant would actually make more sense. At least, the OP's now got what to choose from. :)

Comment: The example I posted was a proof of concept for a much more complicated issue. Your solution actually works better for what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to a LEFT JOIN the combination of Timesheet and the inner join to TimePeriod

The syntax for that is

```
SELECT res.id, res.name, ts.status
FROM Resource res
LEFT JOIN (Timesheet ts 
             INNER JOIN TimePeriod tp 
            ON ts.timeperiod_id = tp.id AND tp.week = '2013Week2')
ON ts.resource_id = res.id
```

You might also want to do `COALESCE(ts.status, 'unsubmitted') status` to convert the nulls

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c631/1)

Comment: Sir, I hope you will not take offence if I kiss you on the mouth.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT res.id, res.name, ts.status
FROM [Resource] res
INNER JOIN Timesheet ts ON ts.resource_id = res.id
LEFT JOIN TimePeriod tp ON ts.timeperiod_id = tp.id 
WHERE tp.week = '2013Week2'
```

This is of course without creating the data locally.  If this doesn't work let me know and I'll give it a second try and recreate your structure locally.

Comment: The INNER JOIN to the Timesheet table would not give NULL's for Status, as it would only return existing timesheets.

Comment: This I believe is the same as my first query, just explicitly saying inner. It still only gives my John Smith.

Comment: Sorry its not the same as my first one. Its the same as a different one I tried, but didn't post.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining from your resource table instead

```
SELECT res.id, res.name, ts.status
FROM Resource res
RIGHT JOIN Timesheet ts ON ts.resource_id = res.ID
LEFT JOIN TimePeriod tp on ts.timeperiod_id = tp.id AND tp.week - '2013Week2'
```

That way you should get existant and non existant timesheets for all resources that exist, and only timesheets for your given time period.

Comment: I assume you meant `tp.week = '2013Week2'`. But this seems to have the same problem as my second query. It has 2 entries for John Smith, and the wrong status for Jason Bourne.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works. Reference the SQLfiddle posted below.

```
select r1.id, r1.name, ts.status
from resource r1, resource r2, timesheet ts
where r1.id = r2.id (+) 
and r2.id = ts.resource_id
and ts.timeperiod_id = (select max(id) from timeperiod)
```

EDIT: using a more explicit join syntax:

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.name, ts.status
FROM resource r1
LEFT OUTER JOIN resource r2 ON r1.id = r2.id
JOIN timesheet ts ON r2.id = ts.resource_id
WHERE ts.timeperiod_id = :timeperiod   -- you can use whatever timeperiod you want, doesn't have to be the max(id)
```

Sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9dd71/3

Comment: This doesn't run. I don't know what `(+)` is. Also, I'm not necessarily always selecting the max(id) from timeperiod. I might want to see who didn't feel out there timesheet last week.

Comment: (+) is just a lazy way to do an outer join. You don't have to use the max(id) if you don't want to, I just did that because you specified that you wanted to see who hadn't filled out their timesheet "this week." I'll edit my code to do the joins more explicitly.

Comment: AH, my bad. That was supposed to be an underscore, not a period. That refers to the `timesheet.timeperiod_id`

Comment: I don't know why you're joining resource to itself. But this gives back some undesired results when I look at 2013week2. It gives me one result: Jason Bourne/Created. Jason's status should be NULL, and there should be a row for John Smith.

Answer (score 0):

The code below create three local temp tables with the data your provided above.

Many people do not know that cross apply can be used like a full outer join.

Thus, we want the cross product of the resource entries and the time period entries for this week.  Regardless if someone submitted a time sheet.

The next step is to left join onto the result on both resource id and time period from the time sheet.  This will show both created and submitted entries.

That is assuming an update does not move a created to the submitted column.  Adding another table with 1 = created and 2 = submitted and taking the max value can list the top one.

The result is shown below.

John Miner, the craftydba, www.craftydba.com

[image]

-- Resource table
create table #Resource
(res_id int, res_name varchar(128));

-- Add data
insert into #Resource
values 
(1 , 'John Smith'),
(2 , 'Jason Bourne');

-- Time period table
create table #TimePeriod
(tp_id int, tp_week int);

-- Add data
insert into #TimePeriod
values
(1 , 201301),
(2 , 201302),
(3 , 201303);

-- Time sheet table
create table #TimeSheet
(ts_id int, ts_status varchar(16), res_id int, tp_id int);

-- Add data
insert into #TimeSheet
values
(1, 'Submitted', 1 , 1),
(2, 'Created', 1 , 2),
(3, 'Submitted', 2 , 1);

-- Need both resource and period regardless of time period
select * 
from #Resource r 
 cross apply
 (
    select * from #TimePeriod p1 where p1.tp_week = 201302
 ) as ca_Period 
 left join #TimeSheet s on s.res_id = r.res_id and ca_Period.tp_id= s.tp_id

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It is tested with your data. But you won't get NULL Values for any resource.

**SELECT Resource.id,Resource.Name,TimeSheet.Status FROM  Resource,TimeSheet,TimePeriod WHERE Resource.id = TimeSheet.id AND TimeSheet.TimePeriod_id = TimePeriod.id AND TimePeriod.Week="2013Week1"**

Hope it helps.

Comment: I specifically need the NULL values though.